# Reason for end around carry to do

Tags: computer-science

I know that the r-1 complement for r-base number should do end around carry if the highest bit has carry.

But I cannot figure out why it should do it.

I merely can think about it is the reason may be about the two representations for zero.

ex:

```
 1 1 1 0    (-1)
 0 1 0 1    (+5)  
 ===============
10 0 1 1  =====>(0 1 0 0)
I just can explain it from the result that because its sum is positive, and 1's complement has two representations, so it should add one.
```

ex:

```
 1 1 1 0    (-1)
 1 0 1 0    (-5)  
 ===============
11 0 1 1  =====>(1 0 0 1)
And I cannot explain it why should add one.
```

What is the really reason for end around carry?

Thx for you reading it.

Comment: It's just part of the definition of ones' complement arithmetic.

Comment: It's worth noting that 1's complement is required when creating checksums for a UDP packet. [See here](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/icmp.htm#ICMP%20Header%20Checksum).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

End-around carry is actually rather simple: it changes the modulus of the addition operation from r<sup>n</sup> to r<sup>n</sup>–1, if you think of the numbers as unsigned.  To simplify things, let's talk about binary.

Let's compute (-2) + (-4) using four-bit two's complement arithmetic:

```
  1 1 1 0    (-2)
+ 1 1 0 0  + (-4)
---------  ------
1 1 0 1 0    (-6)
```

Let's keep the carry bit where it is for now.  If you look at the numbers as unsigned integers, we're computing 14 + 12 = 26.  However, addition is done modulo 16, so we get 10, which is the unsigned number which represents -6 (the correct result).

In ones' complement, the numbers have different representations:

```
  1 1 0 1    (-2)
+ 1 0 1 1  + (-4)
---------  ------
1 1 0 0 0    (-6)
```

Again, let's keep the carry bit where it is.  If you look at the numbers as unsigned integers, we're computing 13 + 11 = 24.  However, due to the wrap-around carry, addition is done modulo 15, so we end up with 9, which represents -6 (the correct result).

So in four-bit two's complement, -2 is equivalent to 14 modulo 16, -4 is equivalent to 12 modulo 16, and -6 is equivalent to 10 modulo 16.

And in four-bit ones' complement, -2 is equivalent to 13 modulo 15, -4 is equivalent to 11 modulo 15, and -6 is equivalent to 9 modulo 15.

**Signed zero:** The reason you get "signed zero" is because there are 16 possible numbers in four bit, but if you're doing modulo-15 arithmetic, then 0 and 15 are equivalent.  That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks @Dietrich Epp, but could you please explain this part: `"However, due to the wrap-around carry, addition is done modulo 15,"`?

Comment: If you have a 4-bit number and ignore the carry bit when you add, then you get modulo 16 arithmetic. If you have a 4-bit number and wrap the carry bit around, then every time you get an extra +1, which is the same effect as doing your arithmetic in base 15.