# How to perform Arithmetic on Ones Complement Numbers and correct overflow?

Tags: binary, computer-science, unsigned, modular-arithmetic, ones-complement

For some backstory, I'm making a program that can do arithmetic on ones complement numbers. To do this I'm converting a binary string into a BigInteger and then performing the math using said BigIntegers, and then converting that back into a binary string. The only problem occurs when the end result goes below -127 or above +127 because I don't know how to correct it due to the nature of ones complement numbers. I was hoping I could somehow instead convert them like unsigned numbers and do like what [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952883/reason-for-end-around-carry-to-do) says to do.

There are also a couple of other questions that I got from reading the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952883/reason-for-end-around-carry-to-do). I put them in block quotes. I'm just asking for information on what they mean, and explain it to me.

Firstly

> I know that the r-1 complement for r-base number should do end around carry if the highest bit has carry.

Secondly

> End-around carry is actually rather simple: it changes the modulus of the addition operation from rn to rn–1.

And lastly

> Again, let's keep the carry bit where it is. If you look at the numbers as unsigned integers, we're computing 13 + 11 = 24. However, due to the wrap-around carry, addition is done modulo 15, so we end up with 9, which represents -6 (the correct result).

If someone can explain these quotes to me and provide some web pages for me to read I would greatly appreciate it! :)